# Submitting a dynamic checkbox form and get values in pairs

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops

I have a form with dynamically added checkboxes - each checkbox together with a hidden field. I need only the checked values displayed in pairs with the hidden field when submitted.

This is what I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="valg[]" value="<?=$hent_data[id]?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="process_id[]" value="<?=$hent_data[process_id]?>" />

<?php
if($_POST[submit] != ""){

$arrlength=count($_POST[valg]);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++) {
$dimen1 = $_POST[valg][$x];
$dimen2 = $_POST[process_id][$x];

echo $hest = "INSERT INTO chosen (kat_ref, prod_ref, process_id) VALUES ($dimen1, '', $dimen2)"."<br/>";
}


}
?>
```

When submitted I get the correct number of rows as I have checked, with the correct checkbox value, BUT, the problem is in the hidden text input. On submit it lists all hidden values.

Let's say in a form with 10 checkboxes (and hidden text input) I have ticked 3 checkboxes I would want the exact 3 hidden text input boxes to be listet together with the ticked checkboxes, but it returns them all, which means that no matter how many checkboxes I check, it'll still parse all the hidden value fields.

Any ideas?

I hope you understand - or else let me know ;-)

Comment: If you set the hidden fields to `disabled` they will not submit at all, you could then `enable` them when you check a `checkbox`

Comment: Sounds interesting - I'm not sure how to enable the fields onsubmit?

Comment: Do you only have one hidden field per checkbox? If so is your `$hent_data[process_id]` unique?

Comment: I have only one hidden field per checkbox, but the $hent_data[process_id] is not unique - $hent_data[id] is however. Maybe I can just switch the two, if unique required... They're both to be stored in the same table, so I guess it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion, to me it seems better to send the checkbox in key=>value

```
<input type="checkbox" name="valg[<?=$hent_data[id]?>]" value="<?=$hent_data[process_id]?>" />
```

This will give you a result in the php side similar to

```
Array
(
    [valg] => Array
        (
            [uniqueKey3] => processID3
            [uniqueKey7] => processID7
            [uniqueKey8] => processID8
        )

)
```

Therefore in the php you can do this:

```
foreach($_POST['valg'] as $ID => $processID){
    echo $hest = "INSERT INTO chosen (kat_ref, prod_ref, process_id) VALUES ($ID, '', $processID)"."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you William George - This works like a charm! I have tested it, and everything seems to work just perfect. Thanks!